# point charge in a magnetic field turned off

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction

So this a problem from Griffith's that I just can't get my head around. A charged particle is stationary in a uniform magnetic field, which is then suddenly turned off. Where does the particle go?
I think it remains stationary but the change in B will induce an E which I cannot figure out without contradictions. What actually happens?

Comment: Please help I am still not settled on this...